# How to get current system FQDN in php-cli?

Tags: php, command-line-interface, fqdn

Is there a way to retrieve current system *fully qualified domain name* using **php-cli**?

What I'm looking for is php function to retrieve the same thing that hostname -f is doing:

```
$ hostname -f  #returns needed: system01.dev.lan
```

I tried following:

```
php_uname('n') // returns: system01
gethostname() // returns: system01
gethostbyname(gethostname()) // returns ip address
gethostbyname(gethostname() . '.') // returns system01
```

$_SERVER dose not exist (because only cli env)

Again, I know I can do this

```
php -r "var_dump(shell_exec('hostname -f'));"
```

But for this trivial task, I think php should have built in functionality to retreive fqdn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following …

```
echo gethostbyaddr("127.0.0.1");
```

This may give a you FQDN, or `localhost` (see below for the cause of this).

… **but**:

even if this works, it is not guaranteed to, and is not at all portable.

**Why is that?**

What you want is basically a *reverse DNS lookup* for the IP address `127.0.0.1`. It doesn't matter if you use `hostname -f` (if available in your *hostname* implementation) or `gethostbyaddr("127.0.0.1")`, the system must always occupy the resolver to find a FQDN for an IP address.

Now if you have a FQDN entry for your IP address in your `/etc/hosts`, then the resolver is able to find the FQDN locally, otherwise it must make a reverse DNS lookup.

This is by design, nothing you can do about it. Fully qualified domain names are the business of DNS, local hosts were never supposed to know about them. Even the `/etc/hosts` entry is more of a hack. (Though a common one, many mail servers need it, too.)

That's why the solution is not portable: If your application is deployed on a server where no FQDN for `127.0.0.1` is in the `/etc/hosts` file, then it will just return the simple host name.

And, obviously, a DNS server can't give you a domain name for a 127.0.0.1 lookup.

There's a little difference between PHP's `gethostbyaddr('127.0.0.1')` and `hostname -f`: The PHP implementation takes the first name assigned to 127.0.0.1, no matter if FQDN or not; `hostname -f` tries to find a FQDN in the names and uses the first one it finds.

The `shell_exec` approach appears valid, but if you'd need to avoid shell commands, you could try reading and parsing `/etc/hosts` directly in PHP; as the syntax is quite simple.

Comment: I don’t have `-f` flag on `hostname`, so I guess that would not be present on every machine either.

Comment: The long version is `--fqdn`, but maybe that's only present in the Debian implementation. Doesn't matter anyway, because it usually you would use something like `dig` for DNS queries on the CLI.

Comment: Yup, that’s not here either. But dig is not really installed by default either, so based on that, I’d really go with your answer over those two.

Comment: Thank you for explicit answer! gethostbyaddr("127.0.0.1") gave me localhost. So I'm sticking with shell_exec() that gives me needed result. I will always have there debian, so it is ok. At least now I understand why it is like it is. :)

Comment: Yup, I wasn't aware of this difference between `gethostbyaddr('127.0.0.1')` and `hostname -f`. I updated the post accordingly, see added two paragraphs at the end.

Answer (score 11):

```
gethostbyaddr(gethostbyname(gethostname()));
```

This returns the FQDN for me while everything else just returns localhost or hostname.

Answer (score 1):

For debian default config the fqdn can be retrieved with:

```
gethostbyaddr('127.0.1.1');
```

Comment: It does work. At first, I thought it was just a duplicate answer because I didn't notice that the IP address is not 127.0.0.1 but 127.0.1.1...